Select row from multiple similar tables
Given the 4 following tables
Person table
name (pk)
age

data_1 table
name (fk, person.name)

data_2 table
name (fk, person.name)

data_3 table
name (fk, person.name)

I want to create a query that will select the age of the person named Adam from the collection of data_1 and data_2 rows. Adam may exist both in data 1 and 2. I tried using multiple joins but then I would be limited to either rows of data_1 or data_2 as the second join would not be from Person.

any expected output? also, it would be far cheaper to have surrogate key.

Why do you have such similar tables? (Meanwhile, UNION ALL the data tables. then JOIN.)

Don't store age. People become older each year and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store DOB instead.

Also, why do you ask the same question several times? You should have improved the previous one instead of deleting it. Now people following that question won't see this.

One more time; a [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

@jarlh The Person table holds much of the data, whilst the other just reference it. I could just make it such that the references are all just in 1 table (that is condensing 1,2,3 into one table and creating another column) but 1 and 2 are merely for recording purposes in my application so i thought it would be better to keep them fragmented.

Is data_3 relevant to this question?

Use multiple joins. If the user might not be in one of the data_X tables, use LEFT JOIN so you get null values for those columns rather than no result for the user. And if the data_X tables have similar column names, use column aliases to distinguish them.
SELECT u.name, u.age, d1.col1 AS d1_col1, d1.col2 AS d1_col2, ..., d2.col1 AS d2_col1, d2.col2 AS d2_col2, ...
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN data_1 AS d1 ON d1.name = u.name
LEFT JOIN data_2 AS d2 ON d2.name = u.name

